# Using markdown wiki-links in Astro framework

Tags: parsing, markdown, astrojs, obsidian

I'm building a website using the Astro framework, and I want to use Markdown wiki-links (links formatted like this `[[link to post]]` from Obsidian to link to other pages on my site. For example, I want to be able to write `[[Page Name]]` in my Markdown content and have it automatically converted to an HTML link to the page with that name.

What is the easiest and/or right way to accomplish this in Astro? Is there a built-in way to parse Markdown wikilinks, or do I need to use a third-party library? And how can I integrate this functionality into my Astro theme?

I tried using remark plugin, wiki-link-parser etc., but had trouble making it work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this and it might be useful for you: https://rachsmith.com/automating-obsidian-to-astro/

Answer (score 4):

As I am also maintaining a blog website using Astro and managing blog contents of my site using Obsidian, my experience might be of some help.

## Difference between Obsidian and Astro's markdown parsers

To begin with, I will show the difference between Obsidian and Astro's markdown parser.

- Obsidian. Obsidian adds a few useful syntaxes to the [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org) Specs, including wikilinks and callouts. Obsidian's markdown parser (though close-sourced) is able to parse these elements and turn them into proper HTML.
- Astro. On the other hand, Astro's markdown parser is the open-sourced [`remark`](https://github.com/remarkjs/remark). `Remark` is written according to the CommonMark Specs, and therefore it does not support wikilinks. However, `remark` is extensible, and we can add some plugins to them make it support customized wiki link syntax.

So the main challenge here is to get a plugin of remark that can add wiki link syntax support to `remark`. Fortunately, you would be able to find one existing plugin [`@portaljs/remark-wiki-link`](https://github.com/datopian/portaljs/tree/main/packages/remark-wiki-link).

## Add `@portaljs/remark-wiki-link` into Your Astro Project

After installation of this plugin, to make `@portaljs/remark-wiki-link` work, you also need to configure it. My suggestion is that

- either you pass all pages' urls to this plugin's `permalinks` option, from which it can find the correct page url corresponding to `Page Name` in your wiki link `[[Page Name]]`;
- or use absolute wiki link paths in Obsidian, and make this plugin auto-generate the url of `[[Page Name]]`.

I have chosen the second approach, because it is more convenient. Here I post the related code segment inside `astro.config.mjs` file:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "astro/config";
import wikiLinkPlugin from "@portaljs/remark-wiki-link";

// Here I assume your pages' urls are of format
// https://yourwebsite.com/posts/slug
// where slug is the slug of your markdown content
const pageUrlPathPrefix = 'posts/';

export default defineConfig({
  markdown: {
    remarkPlugins: [
      [wikiLinkPlugin, { 
        pathFormat: 'obsidian-absolute', 
        // generate url of the linked page.
        // here `slug` would be "Page Name" for wiki link [[Page Name]].
        wikiLinkResolver: (slug) => [pageUrlPathPrefix + slug] 
      }],
    ]
  }
});
```

Inside Obsidian, you will need to do:

1. change your wiki links in Obsidian into absolute format.
2. make sure that `Page Name` inside `[[Page Name]]` be the slug of the page you link to.

   > Note that in Astro, markdown file name does not equal to the slug of that markdown file.

After the steps above, things should work. You can refer to [the official documentation](https://github.com/datopian/portaljs/blob/main/packages/remark-wiki-link/README.md) of this plugin for more information.

There are also other custom syntaxes of markdown in Obsidian, e.g. callouts. If you also want to make Astro parse callouts, I recommend you to check my plugin [`remark-callout`](https://github.com/rk-terence/gz-remark-callout).